# Write files at python

Tags: python

So, I want to make a basic register system at python. I make some dictionary to store the username and password. After user create an account, I want modify the username and password store dictionary using **write()** function, but I don't know how to do that, can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not pretty clear, but if you want to store dictionary in file, you can use `pickle` or `cPickle` (a faster version of `pickle`). These modules provide ways for convinient storing and reading dicts (and some other python objects). You can modify read values and re-write dicts in the same file. 
Example of writing:

```
import cPickle 
favorite_color = {"lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red"} 
cPickle.dump(favorite_color, open("file.txt", "wb"))
```

Exaple of reading:

```
import cPickle
favorite_color = cPickle.load(open("file.txt", "rb"))
# reads {"lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red"}
```

To get more information, read about `cPickle` in [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

Comment: Note, in Python 3 there is no `cpickle`, it was renamed to just `pickle`, and the old `pickle` is no more.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, it is meaningful comment. Topic starter must keep it in mind)

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: cPickle.dump() or pickle.dump()? because the docs said pickle.dump()

Comment: @ArmandDwi `cPickle` is a faster version of `pickle` in Python2 (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle). So you can use `cPickle` in Python2. In Python3 there is no `cPickle`, you should use `pickle`.

Comment: @ArmandDwi documentation is the same for both modules (you can replace `pickle` by `cPickle`)

Answer (score 0):

shelve can also be used instead of pickle.
The shelve module can be used as a simple persistent storage option for Python objects.

```
import shelve
db=shelve.open(#filename)
```

shelve allows you to store and access  data by keys just like dictionaries.
unlike pickle you do not have to modify entire file just to modify one users data.
in shelve objects are stored by keys:

```
db[key]=value
```

store each users data with unique key. Load particular user by key.

```
value=db[key] # to get object stored on database db
```

modify the users data and overwrite on that users key.

```
db[key]= modified_data
```

look at here for demo

```
import shelve
db=shelve.open('data')
d1={'user':'bibek','password':'123'}
d2={'user':'tom','password':456}
#save objects to database
db['1']=d1
db['2']=d2
db.close()
```

to read data from db

```
import shelve
db=shelve.open('data')
d1=db['1']
print(d1)
```

output:

```
{'user':'bibek','password':'123'}
```

now you can modify d1 and save

```
db['1']=#modified d1
db.close()
```

[here](https://pymotw.com/2/shelve/) you can found for more detail about using shelve